# Adding prerequisites Visual C++ runtime redistributable

Tags: installshield-2010

I have problem during installing visual c++ runtime libraries for windows 7.
I prepare the setup using installshield 2010,their is an option to set visual c++ 2010 as prerequisites but no option for VC++ 2008.

How I can create(or anybody created already) .prq file, so that I can build my application.

Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your VC++ 2010 prq file and just edit it. Download the VC++ 2008 and place it on the appropriate folder. Update the prq file by updating the condition as well as the source for your executable file.

Answer (score 7):

You can **download** the prerequisite files using the link from the **AltPrqURL** attribute from one of the installed *.prg* files (default location *c:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012SpringLE\SetupPrerequisites*) and change this link according to your needs. e.g.:

- [http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/microsoft **visual c++ 2008 sp1 redistributable package (x86)**.prq](http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/microsoft%20visual%20c++%202008%20sp1%20redistributable%20package%20%28x86%29.prq)

  - add the following lines for Windows Server 2003 and Windows 8 support:

> <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1" ProductType="2|3"></operatingsystemcondition>
>   <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="2" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>

- [http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/microsoft **visual c++ 2008 sp1 redistributable package (x64)**.prq](http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/microsoft%20visual%20c++%202008%20sp1%20redistributable%20package%20%28x64%29.prq)

  - add the following lines for Windows Server 2003 and Windows 8 support:

> <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4" ProductType="2|3"></operatingsystemcondition>
>   <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="2" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>

The *Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)* is also missing from InstallShield 2012 LE: [http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/microsoft **visual c++ 2010 redistributable package (x64)**.prq](http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/microsoft%20visual%20c++%202010%20redistributable%20package%20%28x64%29.prq)

**Important:** my Visual Studio 2012 + InstallShield 2012 LE did not **list** the new x64 redistributables with their default name. Solution: just **change** the **file names**.

Comment: The x64 redistributable packages are not showing up for me either in visual studio. What did you have to rename the prq files to?

Comment: Oh looks like if you change it to anything other then the default name it will be recognized....weird

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found the .prq file on the Internet for VC++ 2008. This is the content of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetupPrereq>
    <conditions>
        <condition Type="1" Comparison="2" Path="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\D20352A90C039D93DBF6126ECE614057" FileName="" ReturnValue=""/>
    </conditions>
<operatingsystemconditions>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="5" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" ServicePackMajorMin="4"/>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="1" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1" ProductType="1"/>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"/>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="5" MinorVersion="2" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1" ProductType="2|3"/>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="5" MinorVersion="1" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1" ProductType="1"/>
    </operatingsystemconditions>
<files>
    <file LocalFile="&lt;ISProductFolder&gt;\SetupPrerequisites\VC 2008 SP1 Redist\vcredist_x86.exe" URL="http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/d/9/dd9a82d0-52ef-40db-8dab-795376989c03/vcredist_x86.exe" CheckSum="5689D43C3B201DD3810FA3BBA4A6476A" FileSize="0,4216840"/>
</files>
    <execute file="vcredist_x86.exe" cmdline="/q" cmdlinesilent="/q" returncodetoreboot="3010,8192,1641,1046" requiresmsiengine="1"/>
<properties Id="{0BE9572E-8558-404f-B0A5-8C347D145655}" Description="This prerequisite installs the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package for x86-based systems." AltPrqURL="http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/microsoft visual c++ 2008 sp1 redistributable package (x86).prq"/>
    <behavior Reboot="2"/>
</SetupPrereq>
```

This file should be saved into `C:\XXX\InstallShield\YYYY\SetupPrerequisites\` as  `Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86).prq`. Restart your IS an it should be appear in the redistributable option. You could also use InstallShield Prerequisite Editor to change some options or create a new one.